# Choosing a special slot with a condition satisfied

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

Let's say I have 10 slots of which one of them is a special slot which we don't know.
Each slot takes either 1 or 0 randomly and also each slot has 2 neighbor slots (neighbor slots are part of 10 slots itself).

Each slot is equally likely to have either 0 or 1. Special slot is chosen independently of contents.

A typical slot assignment is as follows. Here "7" is considered special slot.
[image]
There are $2^{10}$ data combinations possible.

#### Problem:

I would like to compute probability of selecting a slot that has opposite data to the neighboring slots and also that the chosen slot is the special slot.

By opposite data I mean, if the selected slot's data is 0, then the neighbor slots need to have 1 and 1. In other case if the selected slot's data is 1, then the neighbor slots need to have 0 and 0.

Based on my intuition this is what I thought of.

#### My Answer:

$E_1$=probability that a slot has opposite data to neighbor slots.

$E_2$=probability of choosing a worst slot.

$P(E_1) = 1/8 + 1/8  = 1/4$  (011 or 100 of a selected slot and its neighbor slots)

$P(E_2) = 1/10$ (choosing worst slot)

$P(E_1) P(E_2) = 1/40$

Is my approach correct?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Please edit for clarity.  What makes one slot better than another?  Or are you just saying that someone has secreted selected one of the slots and you are trying to guess which one?  What does "picking up a slot" mean?   Are these slots arranged in a circle?  How are the $0's, 1's$ assigned to slots?

Comment: @lulu Thank you for your comment. I have updated my question. Can you please let me know if this makes sense.

Comment: What does "opposite data" mean here?  Do you just mean that you are excluding the cases $111,000$?  Something else?   And are you saying that you don't know the contents of the slot?  Is each slot equally likely to be $0,1$?  Is the special slot chosen independently of the contents?

Comment: @lulu yes if the selected slot's data is 0, then the neighbor slots needs to have 1 and 1. In other case if the selected slot's data is 1, then the neighbor slots needs to have 0 and 0. This is what I mean by opposite data. 
Yes each slot is equally likely to have either 0 or 1. 
Yes special slot is chosen independently of contents.

Comment: @lulu have added the same into the question as well. Thank you.

Comment: Ok...so the probability that both neighbors have the opposite content is $\frac 14$, and the probability that you guessed the special slot is $\frac 1{10}$.  Given independence, we just multiply those to get $\frac 1{40}$, exactly as you have indicated.

Comment: @lulu Thank you very much for your comments.